# Label Field overlaps with the TextField in a winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a `winform` based Desktop application in C#. The application runs really fine in Windows 7. However when I install in the client system running Windows XP, the application looks very different in terms of look.

I have used `Pixel` units for each of the controls in the design and expected to look the same both in XP and Windows 7.

I tried changing the System Resolution with no success.

To give you an example, the label field was overlapping the Combo field.

[image]

Apart from this, there are number of control where such overlap has happened. Any idea, what could have gone wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the same font you used in Win7 installed on the xp machine?

Comment: The font I am using is "Tw Cen MT" 16px. From the look of it, it looks like font is already installed in the system.

Answer (score 4):

Your XP machine may be using Large Fonts or Extra Large Fonts.

Right-click an open part of the Desktop, click "Properties", select the "Appearance" tab, and you'll see a "Font Size" combo box. If it isn't set to "Normal", change it to "Normal" and reboot.

Comment: Your taking away accessibility. IMO this isn't a solution, recommend OP does something more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373703/495455

Comment: True, it's more of a diagnosis attempt than a solution. Large Fonts may not even be the cause, so figuring that out is the first step.