# Windows Forms DPI scaling

Tags: c#, winforms, dpi

[image]

My application looks good with 100% DPI setting, but when user selects different (125% or 150%) words don't fit in containers. I tried to fix this with solution I found here: [Detect windows font size (100%, 125%, 150%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373260/detect-windows-font-size-100-125-150) which is:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```

It fixed 150% setting (made it a little blur, but that's ok), unfortunately it didn't make the same for 125% which is being used on the PC the app is intended to run.

Is there some easy fix to this or do I have to rearrange every form manually?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application

Comment: At 150%, Windows takes over the scaling and will let your window draw itself into a bitmap.  It then renders that bitmap to the screen, rescaling it to make it bigger.  Yes, that looks fuzzy, you have to declare yourself [dpiAware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034) to stop that.  You are definitely not DPI aware however, you somehow stopped the controls from properly rescaling themselves.  Like they normally do, a screenshot is never a good way to show a coding problem.  Might have something to do with the form's Font property, don't assign it.

Comment: @HansPassant I changed font size in form to 12, is this causing problems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application)

All containers must use the same AutoScaleMode - this part fixed my problem

> It is required that windows app should have same layout at different resolutions means there should be no effect on layout of app on changing resolution. Here are the steps to do this.
>
> 1. Use table layout panel
> 2. Drag control in cell of tablelayoutpanel and set anchor and dock property.
> 3. Set rowspan and colspan properties of dragged control to merge cells
> 4. Set margin and padding of dragged control with respect to cell.
> 5. drag all controls and follow same steps, complete design using tablelayoutpanel
> 6. Now set all columns and rows size of tablelayoutpanel = autosize (or in %)
> 7. Set tablelayoutpanel properties autosize = true,autosizemode = grow and shrink
> 8. Set Forms properties autosize = true,autosizemode = grow and shrink
> 9. Run windows app If your windows app opens in maximum state then set tablelayoutpanel dock property =fill.

Comment: If you use table layout panel and set margin and padding, you [might be in for a bad time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3044516/nested-tablelayoutpanel-is-displayed-with-large-empty-spaces-in-a-windows-forms-application-on-high-dpi-monitors) - better make sure you don't nest those table layout panels.

Comment: How to ignore text zoom in windows for win forms because this solution requires too much work (hundreds of forms)?

Comment: Forced to use a table layout panel? How about we want SplitContainers?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in 2023 :(

Answer (score -1):

## 2023 Update

Add this line to the `Program.cs`

```cs
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
...
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.DpiUnaware); // <-----
...
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

For having the best result try every `HighDpiMode` mode. `DpiUnaware` worked for me, because I designed my form with more than 100%(175%). It depends on your situation.

### More info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/whats-new/net60?view=netdesktop-6.0#new-application-bootstrap