# Button font size different on users PC

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, fonts

I created a project using winforms. A couple of my buttons contained two words. When the software was installed on a users PC, I noticed that the second word did not fit on the button.

I believe this is because for whatever reason the users PC rendered the font I used larger than it appears on my PC and the others I've tested it on. I'm thinking this is probably some user setting in his operating system. The font I used was the default, "Microsoft Sans Serif," 12 point font. The PC that it was installed on was running Windows 7.

Has anyone ever heard of this before/is there a way around it so that I know text will always fit in labels, buttons, etc?

Comment: See: http://blogs.telerik.com/WinFormsTeam/posts/14-02-11/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4075802/62576 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/26073635/62576 might be of use (particularly the first).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers everyone. Not really sure why I got downvoted for this question, but I appreciate the help. I will review these links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be due to differing DPI settings on your machine and your user's. See the following posts.

http://blogs.telerik.com/WinFormsTeam/posts/14-02-11/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-

http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2011/03/handling-dpi-scaling-in-your-net-applications-forms.html