# c# picturebox size changing from display option being set to 125%

Tags: c#, picturebox, display

I have a form with a picturebox in it. I have to set the picture box to stretch image( I don't care if it changes the resolution of the picture) and I load the picture at runtime. Then I want to put buttons on the picture and I read these locations from a file and these locations change depend on which picture is loaded. All works good on my laptop but I do not account for the fact under display you can make text and other items larger. This laptop is set to 125%. What do I use to scale my points or can I just turn this off for my program? I would prefer to just turn it off. It changes my splash screen too.

I am using Visual Studio, C#

Comment: this is perhaps a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373260/detect-windows-font-size-100-125-150) You must take into account your users settings,

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer to my problem.  When I would load my VS project on a machine that was set to 125% it would actually change the size of my controls inside my project.  If you do not want visual studio to change the size of these control you have to set display text and images to 100%, load your VS project, add autoscalemode = none, then close the project, change display text and images back to 125% then all should be good.