# WPF - Receive event when Make text bigger setting is changed in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-10, accessibility

In Windows 10, there is a setting in `Settings -> Ease of Access -> Display -> Make text bigger`

[image: Make text bigger setting on Windows 10]

Is there any event which we can subscribe to when this setting is changed?

In UWP, there is an event `TextScaleFactorChanged` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/text-scaling . Looking for something similar to this for WPF

Update [1/10]: I'm using framework 4.6.2

Comment: does `dpi.DpiX` not let you find this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373260/detect-windows-font-size-100-125-and-150

Comment: @GrahamRitchie This is useful when app starts or a window is open. I want to know when a window is already open and the setting changed.

Comment: Why cant you use your Main Window GotFocus event and check for screen DPI changes there?

When user changes text size in Windows settings your app will have to lose focus so when got focus is fired and you detect the DPI change your app can react accordingly...

Comment: @DeanKuga no luck with that. DPI values don't change