# Is there a way to get text size ratio in Windows programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fonts

I was wondering if there is a way to extract the current text size ratio in Windows (from 100%-225%) similar to getting the current theme used using `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleInformation.DisplayName`? I have no use for it yet since I'm checking the feasibility of getting this info directly using a program.

Comment: Is this answering your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373260/detect-windows-font-size-100-125-and-150

Comment: Hmmm, not the same since the ratio can be anywhere between 100 to 225 (e.g. 144). You could try it if you have Windows 10 using Display settings>Change the size of text, apps, and other items