# Get Windows 10 Text Scaling value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, text, uwp

How can I programmatically retrieve *text scaling value* of Windows in WPF?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to get it? Shouldn't WPF take care of it for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373260/detect-windows-font-size-100-125-and-150

Comment: I need this value @gunr2171, I believe it's possible in UWP, unfortunatelly I need it for WPF and I can't find a way to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows 10

I've found a way to retrieve the *Text Scaling Factor*, without installing any Nuget packages. The idea is to obtain the value directly from the registry.

```
var userKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser;
var softKey = userKey.OpenSubKey("Software");
var micKey = softKey.OpenSubKey("Microsoft");
var accKey = micKey.OpenSubKey("Accessibility");

var factor = accKey.GetValue("TextScaleFactor");`
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a Windows 11 problem, but factor returned `null` for me.

Comment: That worked for windows 10 @VictorChelaru

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you target .NET 5 or an earlier version, you should either set the `TargetFramework` to *net5.0-windows10.0.** or install the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

You can then use the `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings.TextScaleFactor` property:

```
double factor = new UISettings().TextScaleFactor;
```

Comment: I am using `.NET Framework 4.7.2`, I have installed `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` but the `Windows.UI.ViewManagement` namespace is not included( only `Windows.UI.Xaml`

Comment: It does not, there's an error that says *must use `PackageReference`*, in the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.targets`. Is this about adding a reference of the nuget package to my project?

Comment: Content of `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.targets` file.


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="PackageReferenceCheck" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Error Text="Must use PackageReference" Condition="'@(PackageReference)' == ''" />
  </Target>
</Project>`

That's all I am getting

Comment: Did you change the format of your `.csproj` file?

Comment: Ok there's a link there!

Comment: I've restored the nuget packages of my solution, but the same error appears. Isn't that supposed to be a trivial operation?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are using the modern project format. Apparently you (still) don't.

Comment: As you've figgured out I have no clue if I am using the modern or the old one. I've pasted my `.csproject` file. Is that the old one?

Comment: A thousand thanks, can't say that I wasn't panicked for a bit!

Comment: Is `Windows.UI` UWP territory?